# Inserting Duplicate Records into a Temporary Table

Tags: teradata

I have a table ABC with duplicate records. I want to Insert only the duplicate records into another table ABC_DUPE in same schema using Bteq.
Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
Mukesh

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QUALIFY` statement to identify and output duplicates:

Since you didn't share your table... Then consider the following `ABC` table:

```
+----+----+----+
| f1 | f2 | f3 |
+----+----+----+
|  1 | a  | x  |
|  1 | b  | y  |
|  2 | a  | z  |
|  2 | b  | w  |
|  2 | a  | n  |
+----+----+----+
```

Where a unique record is determined by using fields `f1` and `f2`. In this example the record where `f1=2 and f2='a'` is a duplicate with `f3` values `z` and `n`. To output these we use `qualify`:

```
SELECT *
FROM ABC
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY f1, f2) > 1;
```

`QUALIFY` uses Window functions to determine which records to include in the outputted record set. Here we use window function `COUNT(*)` partitioning by our unique composite key `f1, f2`. We keep only records where the `Count(*)` over that partition is greater than `1`.

This will output:

```
+----+----+----+
| f1 | f2 | f3 |
+----+----+----+
|  2 | a  | z  |
|  2 | a  | n  |
+----+----+----+
```

You can use this in a `CREATE TABLE` statement like:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC_DUPE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM ABC
    QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY f1, f2) > 1
) PRIMARY INDEX (f1, f2);
```